# How Like link works in Socialengine

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am working in social engine and developing a plugin and widget in social engine. Say this plugin is about `car` so I want that on listing of my all cars, users can `like` the car.

I have seen in code that request is sent on `activity/index/like` with `action_id` as param. This is the id which is liked by user. Now what I have understood that each of your car entry must be present in `engine4_activity_actions` table.

Again as for as I have understood the following fields are important in that table

```
type | subject_type | subject_id | object_type | object_id
```

I think I can put `mycar` in `type` column, `user` in `subject_type`, `user_id` in `subject_id` But what is object_type and object_id?

First I need to know either my understanding is rite or not? If yes then what I put in above two columns, Or then what is the correct way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

In the table engine4_activity_actions, the type is used to express the action type, for example "like_car" (you have to define it in the engine4_activity_actionTypes table).

```
subject_type: user
subject_id: user_id
object_type: mycar
object_id: car_id
```

Hope this helps you much.